# How to fix 'Could not convert socket to TLS' error in java

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I was using the JavaMail API to send an email containing a text file.  This code I wrote was working perfectly fine last week, however I logged on today and ran the program and received the error in the image I've attached at the bottom.  I updated to the newest version of java 8 and still receive this error.  (I have to use java 8 for the project for work) I looked at the java 8 patch notes for this update and saw the removed of root CA Certificates and I'm not sure what to think/do.  I am posting this question because I cannot find any solution in the other tons of questions about this.

I am running Java 8 (jre 1.8.0_221) and previously was running jre 1.8.0_211.  I do not know what changed as it stopped working today with v.211 and is also not working after I updated to the most recent version of Java 8 with v.221.  I have tried various other properties with no success.  I'm not sure if it is the Java removal of something specific (which I doubt) or if it has to do with firewall permissions any smtp permissions I may or may not have.  Anyways, the code is below for the email sending portion and the code fails at `Transport.send(message);` with error "Could not convert socket to TLS"

```java
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
                props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");

                Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(smtpUsername, u2);
                    }
                });

                try {
                    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
                    message.setSubject(prop.getProperty("Message"));

                    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    messageBodyPart.setText(prop.getProperty("Message"));

                    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(prop.getProperty("text") + ".txt");
                    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                    messageBodyPart.setFileName(prop.getProperty("filename"));
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                    message.setContent(multipart);

                    Transport.send(message);
                    System.out.println("Sent successfully.\n");
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWkf0.png) I am receiving.  Hopefully I have explained thoroughly enough.  This is only my second question I've asked on here.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you downgrade to 1.8.0_211 does it start working again?  Are you connecting to a public mail server or a private mail server?  It's most likely a problem with the SSL/TLS certificate.  You'll find some debugging tips in [SSLNOTES.txt](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/SSLNOTES.txt).

Comment: I will try downgrading again but no it stopped working with 1.8.0_211 and I was researching and found that things out of date can cause that error thus my intuition to update java with no luck.  I'm connecting to my work's private mail server which also lead me to think some permissions have been changed in the past week or so disabling my ability to run the code.  I'll downgrade and report back thanks.

Comment: Update: restored to 1.8.0_211 and I receive the same error as in the original post

Comment: Ok, so this has nothing to do with the version of the JDK.  Something else changed that broke your program.  Check whether the SSL certificate for your server changed.  Try the debugging tips I pointed to.  Also try the tips in this [JavaMail FAQ entry](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#installcert).

Comment: Appreciate both the links you've supplied me @BillShannon, I still have yet to figure out both the cause and a solution but as I commented on the only answer to this post thus far, I'll be in touch with a server manager to see if they can help find the root of this problem.  I'll report back if I manage to figure it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*I am not an expert*, but...

You may be impacted by intentional distrusting of some root certificates in April 2019, or whenever they were applied in your environment (re: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/jdk-distrusting-symantec-tls-certificates).

Comment: It is definitely possible that the certificate expired within the time my code was working til now (a week), but I really can't be sure yet, I don't even know how to go about figuring out if this is the case but I'll hopefully be meeting with someone who runs the server I'm communicating with next week and hopefully I can figure out the problem there and report back here.  Thanks for your input this might be the case in which I will come back and accept the answer if I determine it is.